# How to add a color palette to an Android app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am making a color-changing ball. It contains RGB LEDs and an hc-05 Bluetooth module with Arduino. I have to make an Android app with a color palette, which can send the RGB values of the selected color via Bluetooth to the Arduino. But I can't find how to add a color palette and get the RGB values of the selected color in Android. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select multiple colors at once, you can check out: https://github.com/chiralcode/Android-Color-Picker/

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in color palette widget in Android.  You need to write your own, or use a 3rd party library.  I've used the one at http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/ before.